# resizing facebook like box

Tags: html, css, facebook

http://themuv.com/tester123/bombay3/index.html
i am building this site and have used a facebook like box at bottom left . But the trouble is that i cant limit the width the text fits in . As a result it goes beyond the size of the box. how can a fix the problem??

i want that the names of people who liked the box is displayed correctly and visible and within the width of the box?
any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your plugin from the Facebook site itself, there's a field where you put a width

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can also un-check the faces if it's bugging your design.